# Nestjs pipe works when I manually create entity but not in jest test

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a validation pipe to check input that works when I manually create a product(using postman), but it doesn't check when I run tests. any explanations?

my validator:

```
@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private schema: ObjectSchema) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { error } = this.schema.validate(value);
    if (error) {
      throw new HttpException('Validation failed', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

my controller:

```
  @UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(productSchema))
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto): Promise<Product> {
    return (await this.productsService.create(createProductDto)).product;
  }
```

my test:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [ProductsController],
      providers: [ProductsService],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<ProductsController>(ProductsController);
    service = module.get<ProductsService>(ProductsService);
  });    

describe('create()', () => {
        it('should fail to add a new product', async () => {
          const result: Product = {
            name: 'p',
            price: -100,
            category: 'junk',
          };
    
          expect(await controller.create(result)).toBe(result);
        });
      });
```

my schema:

```
export const productSchema: ObjectSchema = object({
  createProductDto: object().keys({
    name: string().min(5).required(),
    price: number().integer().min(0).default(0),
    category: string().min(5).required(),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipes don't run unless you're going through the HTTP request. Same for other enhancers like guards and interceptors. If you want to test the pipe you can do that with supertest and e2e tests, or you can test the schema directly with joi in a different test suite